# Предикаты, критерии для связи один ко многим

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-jpa, one-to-many

Имеется 2 сущности, связь один ко многим. Я пользуюсь  JPA (Hibernate), чтобы объединить эти таблицы и создаю критерии для определенного набора результатов, но критерии, которые я определяю не дают результат для сущности Book.

```java
public class Author {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="author", initialValue=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "author")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Book {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="book", initialValue=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "book")
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="author_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
     private Author author;

}
```

Вот предикат, я делаю фильтр по title

```java
 @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root root, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        List <Predicate> list=new ArrayList<>();
            if(filter.getTitle() !=null)
                list.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("title"), filter.getTitle()));
if(filter.getTitleLike() !=null)
                list.add(criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("title"), "%" +filter.getTitleLike()+ "%"));
        }
        return criteriaBuilder.and(list.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
```

По сути, мне выдается StackOverFlow и фильтрация не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а более подробный стек ошибки? переполнение может быть только в том случае, если в методах `equals` и `hashCode` у автора участвует книга, а у книги участвует автор, отсюда и переполнение

Comment: не понятно, что вы хотите сделать. Вы добавляете в условие запроса одно и тоже поле с разными условиями если у вас выполнится два условия ??

Comment: и поменяйте в объекте Author `private Collection<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();` на `private Collection<Book> books;` зачем вы присваиваете пустой список?

Comment: Дебаг в студию. Где именно выдаётся SO? Может быть такое, что фильтрация работает, а вот то, как Вы обрабатываете результат фильтрации не работает. Какая-нибудь рекурсия имеется?

Comment: @Z.John ничего страшного в `Collection<Book> books = new ArrayList<>()`; нет. Не пугайте автора.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverFlow получается, потому что у вас циклическая зависимость возникает при попытке инициализации одной из связанных сущностей.

В Book есть ссылка на Author, которую обязательно нужно инициализировать, а в Author на Book

Сделайте класс Author так

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
private Collection<Book> books;
```

А класс Book так:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
private Author author;
```

Comment: Да всё у него нормально с коллекцией буков в авторе.